# Spring Integration Http+rabbitmq

Tags: spring-integration

I need to override HTTP status code depending on  the Exception thrown. I tried it with Spring Integration 4.1 which does not work, moved to version 4.2 where it is possible to override but it always throws 
ErrorMessage

> payload=org.springframework.integration.MessageTimeoutException: No
>   reply received within timeout, headers={timestamp=1453640013026,
>   id=83248ecf-2be8-dc59-fff4-db4fb2981d5f,
>   errorChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@6736e63e,
>   replyChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@6736e63e}

I cannot handle any other exception due to this? Any help

Comment: I tried to reword your question, but in places there were just some things missing, that I am not sure, if this corresponds to your actual intent of the question.

Comment: Please, share the config and point out where you would like to see it working